# Android Launcher, Bounding Box not throwing the event ACTION_DRAG_EXITED

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-launcher

I am new to Android Development. I'm currently put into middle of a project development. In my project, people have implemented a custom launcher.

In the launcher home screen if the user drags and drops an icon to extreme of the screen then it should navigate the user to the next screen with that app icon still selected and in drag state. In my application, I have to move the icon to the very extreme to move it to next screen and some time it won't go to next screen at all.

I have come across Drag and Drop examples specified in Android Dev guide and came to know that if the user moves the icon out of the bounding box then it will provide the event ACTION_DRAG_EXITED. But in my application it is getting triggered only if I push it to the extreme end.

So I need to push the icon to next screen at a reasonable distance. To achieve this, which one I need to look into ?

Like Bounding box, or how to manually alter the bounding box value ? Or any other thing I need to look so that I can go in a right direction.

Kindly Advice.

Comment: On Further investigation on the code by logging all the events, solved the issue. There was a variable declared with a value of 20, which checks for the scroll zone. Changed it to 60 and working fine now.